# TypeScript: Enforce that an interface only contains property-keys that are present in a specific class

Tags: typescript

I have the following class that is used as an entity for an object-relational-mapper:

```
@Entity("MyEntity")
export class MyEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 2000 * 2 })
  data!: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created!: Date;
}
```

Now for some reason, most of my code does not use this class.
Instead, the code uses a "model"-interface that is a loose subset of this class:

```
export interface MyModel {
  id: number;
  data: string;
}
```

A problem with this approach is that the model-interfaces can get easily out-of-sync with the entity-classes.
This leads to my question:

**How can I statically enforce that all property-keys of `MyModel` are also present in `MyEntity`?**

Comment: Usually you go the other way. Define an interface (a contract) and then make your class to implement the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure If I got your question, but you can `implement` the interface and enforce those properties.

```js
interface MyModel {
    id: number;
    data: string;
}

// This throws: Class 'MyEntity' incorrectly implements interface 'MyModel'.
class MyEntity implements MyModel {

}

// This works
class MyEntity implements MyModel {
    data: string;
    id: number;
}
```

Comment: My question was actually the opposite direction. Take the interface and ensure that the interface "complies" to the class (without changing a single line of the class). This would yield a more convoluted and sophisticated solution than a simple "implements".

Comment: Do you mean your interface should "implement" your class?

Comment: When you want to ensure certain properties in a class with an interface, `implements` is the way to go. You cannot just "compile" them into the class as the interface has no value declaration what so ever (just type) and so they would technically just sit around as undefined. You may want to explain to me why you want to achieve this, and what you want to do with it.

Comment: You can technically write an interface which `extends` a class if that is your desire.

Comment: There might be reasons for it, perhaps to experiment with advanced TypeScript features. But I decided that it is not worth the hassle and therefore accepted this answer.

Comment: Hm... I'd be glad to help... but if you don't feel like it, that's fine as well :)

Comment: Well, while we are at it. Could you expand your answer such that a similar goal is achieved without changing a single line of MyEntity (e.g. without the "implements"). It would be too easy to take the obvious solution ;)

Comment: you want to make sure `MyEntity` includes the properties of `MyModel` without telling the compiler to do so? Isn't that like ordering food without actually telling what you want?

Comment: Not quite. I want to make sure that MyModel only contains properties of MyEntity, but not any other properties. Think of it like: MyEntity is the source of truth, whereas MyModel must has a subset of MyEntity's properties.

Comment: Okay, I'm walking on thin ice now with my knowledge but you can extend the `MyEntity` class by doing `interface MyModel extends MyEntity`. Every class or object that now implements `MyModel` needs to both satisfy the classes and the interfaces construct.